# Login button not setting the textview text correctly Android

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

I have been working at this for a hot minute now and I can't figure out why  the text won't be set correctly when the button is pressed. It is set correctly everywhere else just not this spot. I tried moving it around in different places but still no effect.
the first loginSuccess.setText("Checking Credintails"); is not working. The others work fine in the code which has me baffled. Any help with this would be appreciated.The loginSuccess.setText("Checking Credintails"); should be called when the button is pushed.

So here is my code for the button OnClick

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loginSuccess.setText("Checking Credintails");

            //test to see if there is a connection
            ConnectionTester ct = new ConnectionTester();
            boolean online = ct.isOnline(v.getContext());
            boolean issue = false;


            Tracker longinTracker = ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication()).getDefaultTracker();
            userName = user.getText().toString();
            passWord = pass.getText().toString();
            LoginJsonParser ljp = new LoginJsonParser();

            if(online)
            {
                try {
                    ljp.checkUsername(loginUrl, userName, passWord);
                    canLogin = ljp.returnedResult;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (NullPointerException ne)
                {
                    issue = true;
                    loginSuccess.setText("接続の問題");
                    Log.d("Null point ", "Jsonl login");
                }
                //if(userName.equals("admin") && passWord.equals("admin")0
                if(canLogin == true)
                {
                    //Write to the ShardedPreference to store for later use
                    Log.d("My user name " , userName);
                    Log.d("My Password " , passWord);
                    MySharedPerference.writeString(getApplicationContext(),MySharedPerference.USERNAME, userName);
                    MySharedPerference.writeString(getApplicationContext(),MySharedPerference.PASSWORD, passWord);
                    //build login event
                    //call this first otherwise it may not be called and wont post to the servers
                    longinTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                    .setCategory(getString(R.string.eventCategory))
                                    .setAction(getString(R.string.loginevent))
                                    .build()
                    );
                    //Start downloaing and processing customer data
                    //Also open up the Loading screeen animation
                    loadingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loginSuccess.setText("Loging you in now");
                    donwloadCustomerData();

                }else
                {
                    if(issue != true)
                    {
                        loginSuccess.setText("パスワードが違います");
                    }else{
                        loginSuccess.setText("接続に関する問題");
                    }

                }
            }else
            {
                Intent noCon = new Intent(v.getContext(), NoConnection.class);
                startActivity(noCon);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: If there is an IOException then your set Text won't work. Maybe that is the case, try placing another setText in your IOException block

Comment: check your textview id is correct or not. @MNM

Comment: I suspect there isn't any [real] delay between the first `setText()` call and one of the others. Is that possible?

Comment: there can be only two problems here , either logic or code and we can't see both and what you mean by `correctly`, you should state the behavior completely

Comment: `loginSuccess.setText("Checking Credintails")` doesn't work, right?

Comment: Yes when I try to change the loginSuccess text it does not change at all. But it changed at the other places

Comment: you've got `loginSuccess.setText()` in other places down the line. perhaps that it gets to those other points faster than you can see it, so it IS changing it, but gets changed again in ms.

Comment: log it right after you set it, `Log.d(tag, loginSuccess.getText().toString())` to see if it really became "Checking Credintails" or just comment-out everything below it for a test to visually see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping with this. I figured what was happing with the setText() problem. 
I was changing right to a degree so it would change but the UI would not update before it started to download the data from the server. So the downloading was taking over the thread and not letting the UI update and change. so that is why the later setText worked but not the first setText. After I put all the downloading into its own thread the set text works fine. I appreciate everyones help with this all your ideas lead me to think about this in a new light and solve this issue. Thank you again.